# Operador de entrada para una clase

Tags: c++, poo, clase, operador

Estoy haciendo una clase muy sencilla, racional, que tiene las variables de numerador y denominador.

Al implementar el operador de entrada me da un error que no se como solucionar.
D:\C++\EjercicioCasa\src\Racional.cpp|46|error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Racional&' to an rvalue of type 'Racional'|

Os incluyo los archivos de clase e implementacion a continuacion

Archivo Clase:

```
#ifndef RACIONAL_H
#define RACIONAL_H
#include <iostream>

class Racional
{
    public:
        Racional(); //Default constructor
        Racional(int num, int den); //Constructor
        Racional(Racional& r); //Copy constructor


        Racional& operator=(Racional& racional);    //Assigment operator
        Racional& operator+=(Racional& racional);
        int denominador();
        int numerador();

    private:
        int num;
        int den;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Racional& r);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Racional& r);
#endif // RACIONAL_H
```

Archivo Implementacion:

```
#include "Racional.h"
#include <iostream>
Racional::Racional(): num(0), den(1)
{
}

Racional::Racional(int num, int den): num(num),den(den)
{
}

Racional::Racional(Racional& r): num(r.num) , den(r.den)
{
}
Racional& Racional::operator+=(Racional& r)
{
    num= num*r.den + r.num*den;
    den = den*r.den;
    return *this;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,Racional& r)
{
    out<<r.numerador();
    out<<'/';
    out<<r.denominador();
    return out;
}
Racional::denominador()
{
    return den;
}

Racional::numerador()
{
    return num;
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Racional& r)
{
    int num;
    int den;
    char ch;

    in>>num;
    in>>ch;
    in>>den;

    r = Racional(num,den);
    return in;
}
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda, el errror me lo da en la  linea 46 del archivo de implementacion, diria que tiene algo que ver con la referencia pero no se como solucionarlo.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El compilador reporta [estos errores](https://cppinsights.io/s/330e3ce4):

```
/home/insights/insights.cpp:52:11: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
Racional::denominador()
          ^
/home/insights/insights.cpp:57:11: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
Racional::numerador()
          ^
/home/insights/insights.cpp:71:7: error: no viable overloaded '='
    r = Racional(num,den);
    ~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/insights/insights.cpp:13:19: note: candidate function not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument
        Racional& operator=(Racional& racional);    //Assigment operator
                  ^
```

Los primeros 2 dicen que a la función `numerador` y `denominador` les falta el tipo de retorno (`int`).

El segundo dice que no se encontró ninguna sobrecarga válida.

La explicación es que el operando derecho de la instrucción

```
r = Racional(num,den);
```

es un **rvalue** pero la única función candidata recibe un **lvalue**:

```
Racional& operator=(Racional& racional);
```

Hay más cuestiones sobre tipos de valores pero resumidamente, un **rvalue** es un valor que aparece a la derecha de una asignación, por ejemplo un literal. Mientras que un **lvalue** puede aparecer a la izquierda también (como una variable). Más información [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

---

En C++ las [referencias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) pueden ser a estos dos tipos de valores. Una referencia a un **lvalue** tiene la forma:

```
tipo & referencia;
```

Una a un **rvalue** tiene esta forma:

```
tipo && referencia;
```

Dicho esto, puedes intuir que necesitas agregar una nueva sobrecarga a un **rvalue** (y es así). Esta sobrecarga recibe el nombre de [**move assignment**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment).

```
Racional& operator=(Racional&& racional);
```

Otra cosa que deberías hacer es agregar el atributo `const` al parámetro de copia asignación:

```
Racional& operator=(const Racional& racional);
```

De hecho, recomiendo que siempre que no modifiques el valor de una referencia lvalue la marques como constante. Nunca vi un código con una referencia rvalue constante.

Si vas a dar este paso, asegúrate de marcar como `const` las funciones que no modifiquen las variables de tus clases.

Por ejemplo `denominador` y `numerador` no las modifican así que puedes marcarlas como const:

int denominador() const;
int numerador() const;

---

Por cierto, puedes pasar un rvalue a una referencia lvalue constante.

Así lo dice la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Notes):

> If only the copy assignment is provided, all argument categories select it (as long as it takes its argument by value or as reference to const, since rvalues can bind to const references), which makes copy assignment the fallback for move assignment, when move is unavailable.

Por ejemplo la función:

```
Racional& operator=(const Racional& racional);
```

Answer (score 1):

Te has olvidado el tipo el retorno(int) en los métodos e acceso en tu implementación.

Tu clase está mal diseñada, no tiene funcionalidad en un entorno constante. Estás usando el operador de asignación con un objeto temporal como operando derecho:

```
//r= Racional(num,den); //estas asignado un objeto temporal.
Racional temp(num,den);
r = temp;//temp ya no es un objeto temporal
```

Con la modificación anterior tu código ya compila. El siguiente fragmento es un ejemplo de la declaración de tu clase bien diseñada, debes notar el uso del calificador constante(const) en el constructor de copia, el operador de asignación, los métodos de acceso y la sobrecarga del operador de inserción en el flujo estándar:

```
#ifndef RACIONAL_H
#define RACIONAL_H
#include <iostream>

class Racional
{
public:
    Racional(); //Default constructor
    Racional(int num, int den); //Constructor
    //Aquí => en el parámetro 
    Racional(const Racional& r); //Copy constructor

    //Aquí => parámetro 
    Racional& operator=(const Racional& racional);    //Assigment operator
    Racional& operator+=(const Racional& racional);

    //Aquí => En los métodos de acceso
    int denominador() const;
    int numerador() const;

private:
    int num;
    int den;
};
//aquí =>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Racional& r);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Racional& r);
#endif // RACIONAL_H
```

Con este diseño ya es válida la línea que te da conflicto al compilar:

```
r= Racional(num, den);
```